# Overloading and Array

Tags: php, overloading

```
<?php
class MaClasse
{
    private $attributs = array();
    private $unAttributPrive;

    public function __get ($nom)
    {
        if (isset ($this->attributs[$nom]))
            return $this->attributs[$nom];
    }

    public function __set ($nom, $valeur)
    {
        $this->attributs[$nom] = $valeur;
    }

    public function afficherAttributs()
    {
        echo '<pre>', print_r ($this->attributs, true), '</pre>';
    }
}

$obj = new MaClasse;

$obj->attribut = 'Simple test';
$obj->unAttributPrive = 'Autre simple test';

echo $obj->attribut;
echo $obj->autreAtribut;
$obj->afficherAttributs();   
?>
```

I don't understand why  the second variable does not show anything?
But in the array it does exist.

Comment: Are you trying to set a private variable?

Comment: You are setting `unAttributPrive` and echoing `autreAtribut`. Try `echo $obj->unAttributPrive;`.

Comment: Sorry guys !! i thought it was the same !! thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `unAttributPrive`, but getting `autreAtribut`.

Comment: I set both : $obj->attribut = 'Simple test';
$obj->unAttributPrive = 'Autre simple test';

Comment: @satyres: Correct, but you're `echo $obj->autreAtribut;` rather than `echo $obj-> unAttributPrive;`

Comment: Yes it's true !! Sorry guys !! i thought it was the same !! thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a whim and guess because you are spelling your variable names wrong. If you are looking to echo $obj->unAttributPrive

Comment: This is not the main problem : i don't uderstand why the second variable does not show his content ?

Comment: Because there is no content to show? I think Josh and I are trying to say you haven't stored anything into that second variable.

Comment: Sorry guys !! i thought it was the same !!